# getChildByName with Regex

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've got:

```
stage.getChildByName("button_1")

button_1

button_2

button_3

button_...

button_15
```

I could easily create a var XSample to store the number, run for statement, increase +1 XSample and use XSample.toString() with "button_"

But things are going to be a little more complex, so I need to get everything after button_

```
stage.getChildByName("button_" + everything)
// it could be button_5, button_Ag6, button_0086, button_93 and so on
```

How can I do that with Regex?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Usecase:**

```
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.Sprite;

var shapeContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();

addChild(shapeContainer);

var shape_1:Shape = new Shape();
shape_1.name = "shape_ONE";

var shape_2:Shape = new Shape();
shape_2.name = "displayObject_TWO";

var shape_3:Shape = new Shape();
shape_3.name = "shape_THREE";

shapeContainer.addChild(shape_1);
shapeContainer.addChild(shape_2);
shapeContainer.addChild(shape_3);

trace(getIndicesWithChildNamePattern("shape_", shapeContainer)); //0, 2
```

**Using String.indexOf():**

```
function getIndicesWithChildNamePattern(pattern:String, container:DisplayObjectContainer):Vector.<uint>
{
    var indices:Vector.<uint> = new Vector.<uint>();

    for (var i:uint = 0; i < container.numChildren; i++)
    {
        if (container.getChildAt(i).name.indexOf(pattern) != -1)
        {
            indices.push(i);
        }
    }

    return indices;
}
```

**Using Regular Expressions:**

```
function getIndicesWithChildNamePattern(pattern:String, container:DisplayObjectContainer):Vector.<uint>
{
    var indices:Vector.<uint> = new Vector.<uint>();
    var regExp:RegExp = new RegExp(pattern, "g");

    for (var i:uint = 0; i < container.numChildren; i++)
    {
        if (container.getChildAt(i).name.match(regExp).length)
        {
            indices.push(i);
        }
    }

    return indices;
}
```